# jQuery Slider resets in Fiddle, but not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everything (should) be the same, from **[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmBa7/2/)** to **[my site](http://qmedichealth.com/)**. I'm using this slider plugin. However, when I get to the last < li > and click next, it won't start over, and instead shows shows the logos from the first < li > in the last one. (see image). I would the the slider to loop through like normal, and for the logos not to appear on the bottom of the last < li >.

[image]

```
     $('#slider1').bxSlider({
     mode: 'horizontal',
     auto: false,
     autoControls: false,
     pause: 5000
    });
```

Comment: For the time being, I got rid of the arrows to make it work. So I guess I'm good for now, thanks.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using. You may be using the wrong version or something (not likely).